# Jquery anchor hover fade

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to create a jquery "fade" effect on hover (on an anchor with image inside)?

***HTML***

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">
            <img src="http://www.littlegiant.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Meccano-293x170.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

***CSS***

```
#list li a img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

#list li a {
    display: block;
    width: 293px;
    height: 170px;
}
#list li a:hover {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ecFBK/4/

When you hover over the red appears which is correct - I just don't know how to make it fade in using jquery. Please no CSS3 suggestions.

Comment: Check out some of the related questions (on the right below the ad), some of them look like they answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake it by adding an overlay to the link.  You'll need to add `position: relative` to the link CSS, and remove the `a:hover` CSS, then you can do something like this for the jQuery:

```
$('#list li a').hover(function(ev){
    if (!$(this).find('.hover').length) {
        $('<span class="hover">').css({
            'background-color': 'red',
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'opacity': 0,
            'width': 293,
            'height': 170,
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0
        }).appendTo($(this));
    }
    $(this).find('.hover').stop(true, true).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2000);
}, function(ev){
    $(this).find('.hover').stop(true, true).animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000);
});
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ecFBK/10/)

Comment: This is very close and thank you! However, when I move the cursor around the site there are duplicates of the "span" being made and more out of place hovers are appearing? Where it has background-color in the jquery I have replaced this with background image as on hover it is supposed to be an image

Comment: Awesome thanks for that - now we run into another issue.. it doesn't work in google chrome or IE? :-(

Answer (score 1):

Impossible with your HTML markup.
You need to fadeIn a `span` element, not an `a` that actually holds your image!

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/ecFBK/6/)*

jQuery:

```
$('#list li a').hover(function(){
   $('span', this).stop().fadeIn(500);
}, function(){
  $('span', this).stop().fadeOut(500);    
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">
            <img src="http://www.littlegiant.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Meccano-293x170.jpg" alt="" />
            <span>Description here!</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#list li a {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    width: 293px;
    height: 170px;
}

#list li a img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

#list li a span {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
    background:red;      
}
```

Comment: question - since the span is in there and has text... how would you make it a block element to display a background image with it being set to display: none; ?

Comment: @JordyVialoux I don't understand your question. Please can you be more descriptive? (If I understood well: set a width and height to the span element.)